# Post Data using Jersey

Tags: jersey

I am trying to make a request to a 3rd paty that is equivalent to the following:

```
curl -G -X GET -u {API KEY}:X https://some.com/api/head/remotelogin.json -d 'id=1234&msg=hello'
```

The `id` is also used by third party to validate the request.

Below is the interface that I wrote:

```
public interface ThirdParty Client {
    @POST
    @Path("api/head/remotelogin.json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumer(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    Response authenticate(@HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String authHeader, String payload)
}
```

I am not sure how to build the payload, and am I using `@Consumer(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` correctly?

I am doing my post request in Java like

`final Response response = ThirdPartyClient.authenticate(base64encoded("{API KEY}:X"), "id=1234&msg=hello");`

I am getting `200`, but the `id` is wrong.

I am fairly new to Jersey, and I spent the entire afternoon reading the docs and trying things out.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the id is wrong'? Where? What is the value of the `payload`  parameter in `authenticate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some sleep, the answer is...

```
    @GET
    @Path("api/head/remotelogin.json")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Response authenticate(@HeaderParam(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String authHeader, @QueryParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("msg") String msg);
```

`final Response response = ThirdPartyClient.authenticate("Basic " + base64encoded("{API KEY}:X"), "1234", "hello");`

The `"Basic "` is essential in here.